# API Request from GitHub pages doesn't work ("mixed block")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, github, github-pages

So I deployed all of my React apps that are using an API. I am having problems sending this api and something block them and so my apps aren't working.

Note: all of my requests are cors so there is no problem with them.

[github block my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJkO.png)

and this is link to the project in picture [news-blog](https://ariaman-act.github.io/news-blog/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to fetch non-secure (http) content from a secure (https) site, which violates the site's [Content-Security-Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). This is an insecure behavior as far as modern browsers are concerned.

From MDN:

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows web site administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load for a given page. With a few exceptions, policies mostly involve specifying server origins and script endpoints. This helps guard against cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).

The right way of solving this would be to load the data from a secure source. For example, instead of fetching from `http://newsapi.org/v2/everything`, try `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything` (note the difference between http and https).